# How to trigger a OnChange type of event in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have this onchange event in my JS that according to a select list, changes the maxlength for the textboxes under it. Now i want to be able to do this server side just incase if a user has JS turned off.

I have some code behind code but it only works after the selection is made and then the page is refreshed, i want to be able to work without the refresh factor or some sort of auto refresh as soon as the user selects an option from the dropdown.

This is my Code Behind:-

```
protected void ListPayment_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListPayment.SelectedIndex == 4)
        {

            TextBoxCCN.MaxLength = 15;
            TextCSS.MaxLength = 4;
        }

        else if (ListPayment.SelectedIndex != 4)
        {

            TextBoxCCN.MaxLength = 16;
            TextCSS.MaxLength = 3;
        }
    }
```

This is my HTML

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ListPayment" runat="server" 
  onchange="ValidateCCN();" 
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListPayment_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select...</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Visa">Visa</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="MasterCard">MasterCard</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Discover">Discover</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="American Express">American Express</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `AutoPostBack` property is for:

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true"...
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx

## EDIT:

Full revised code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ListPayment" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
  onchange="ValidateCCN();" 
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListPayment_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select...</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Visa">Visa</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="MasterCard">MasterCard</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Discover">Discover</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="American Express">American Express</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: where do i add that? above the select list?

Comment: I've added it to your `DropDownList` tag in my answer. See my edit for full code.

Comment: yep okay, so do i have to move all my code behind code into the page load function? because it isnt working as of now

Comment: @rookie26 no, setting `AutoPostBack="true"` should do the trick.  When you change the value in the select list is it causing the page to postback?  If not I would look what `ValidateCCN()` is doing client side as this may be preventing the postback.

Comment: Why do you think you'd have to do that as well as the suggestion I've just made?

Comment: it wasnt working with the suggestion you made since i have no postback. I put all my codebehind code into page load. Thanks for all your help. If i have time, i will investigate about it later as currently on a deadline

Comment: None of the code you've posted here can or should be in page load, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: if i use the code as above, the max length isnt set for the textboxes also the link you mentioned above, it has everything in the pageload function so thats why im putting mine in the page load function